# How to check if a SQL query from a variable input returns a row in Python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a function to check if a username is already taken.

```
signup_username = input("Username: ")

check_username = cursor.execute(f"""SELECT username
                                    FROM user
                                    WHERE username = '{signup_username}'""")

while check_username.rowcount != 0:

    print("Username already taken.")
    signup_username = input("Username: ")
```

For some reason, even though there is only one row in the user table yet, no matter what I type in the signup_username input, it's stuck in the while loop, as if the username was already taken.

My database is connected. Everything else works, but for some reason, this is not working. Got any idea how to fix it?

Comment: print check_username.rowcount before while part, what is printed?

Comment: @marke Uhhh... It prints -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two issues in your code, the first one being that you're not changing the query inside your loop and thus still fetching data with the original username.
The second one being that `.rowcount` always returns `-1` for `SELECT` queries. If you tried printing your variables

```
>>> cursor.execute("select * from user").rowcount
-1
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount):

> As required by the Python DB API Spec,
>   the rowcount attribute “is -1 in case
>   no executeXX() has been performed on
>   the cursor or the rowcount of the last
>   operation is not determinable by the
>   interface”.
>
> **This includes `SELECT` statements
>   because we cannot determine the number
>   of rows a query produced until all
>   rows were fetched.**

That means **all** `SELECT` statements **won't have a `rowcount`**.

What you'd want to do instead is running `.fetchone()` and checking if that is not empty. If so that means you already have that username in db

Comment: I've replaced the `check_username.rowcount != 0` with `check_username.fetchone() is not None` and it works. Thanks a lot!